# Projecting ArcGIS feature dataset containing relationship classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, relationship-class

I have a geodatabase with more then 50 feature classes and 60-70 tables.
The feature classes are inside a feature dataset which is using a projected cooridnate system.
There are 250+ relationship classes inside the feature dataset linking feature classes with each other as well as with tables.
Similarly there are relationship classes outside feature dataset as well.

My task is to convert the projection of all feature classes from Projected to WGS84. 
If I do it one by one and write to a new feature dataset I lose the relationship class. 
If I apply project tool on feature data set then it creates a new feature dataset with feature classes but only few relationship classes are there.

How should I project a feature data set (all feature classes)  keeping all the relationship classes?

Even if a break all relationship classes and create a new feature data set is there a way that I can copy the relationship classess without creating each one by one?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 and I have ArcGIS Pro 2.3 as well.

Comment: You might want to try to export an *empty* XML document, then edit the XML to change the spatial reference XML.  The you could just project in the data.  But there are a number of options, and it should all be scriptable.

Comment: Thats exactly what i am doing but with xml its taking me time as xml is quite big

Comment: That's why I use Java or Python utilities to iterate documents.

Comment: Yes i am also parsing it using minidom in Python

Comment: Can you tell me apart from index where else should i change the projection ?